# Show that question given a consistent market

Tags: finance

Stuck on a "show that" question that is more interest rate related but I'll provide all the information needed below.

Given a consistent market, show that:

When $$A(0,t) = 1 + 0.05t,    i_h(t)=\frac{(0.05)}{1+0.05t}$$
and that when $$A(0,t) = 1.05^t,    i_h(t)=\frac{(1.05)^h-1}{h}$$

The definitions are listed below:
$A(t,t+n)=1+h*i_h(t)$

A consistent market is one where $A(t_0,t_n)=A(t_0,t_1)*A(t_1,t_2)*...*A(t_{(n-1)},t_n)$

$i_h(t) = \frac{j}{h}$ where j is effective rate of interest for the period $(t,t+h)$

Please let me know if the question is unclear, as I have been struggling with this proof for a while now! I don't understand why for the first result $ i_h(t)=0.05$ is not correct.

I am also wondering how the first result is independent of $h$ and how the second result is independent of $t$.

Comment: Show that ... ? What has to be shown ? That´s unclear to me.